# TeXstudio does not find MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, installing, texstudio

How do I make TeXstudio find the MiKTeX  file?

I downloaded the MiKTeX distribution first and then TeXstudio and put them in the same folder.

I have tried reinstalling TeXstudio and I have tried deleting the `.ini` file but neither works...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you install TeX Studio *before* MiKTeX? Also, certainly do *not* install TeX Studio in MiKTeX directory

Comment: I installed Miktex first and then Texstudio. I placed them both in Programe files..

Comment: Don't install TeX Studio in the MiKTeX directory.

Comment: I did not, but i did install the two distributions in the same folder

Comment: That should be  no problem. Check if you can launch latex from the command line. Maybe  the installation of MiKTeX was defective.

Comment: From what command line? How do do that?

Comment: I mean the shell. It's `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 6):

I have downloaded both in portable versions and just fix it adding: "....\texmfs\install\miktex\bin" to Path in System Variables in Environment Variables.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I solved the problem this way:

> Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Commands > LaTeX

The LaTeX-commands can be found in a sub-folder of the MiKTeX installation folder.

First time, I tried: "C:/Program Files/LaTeX/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/imakeidx.sty"

After a reboot of TeXstudio, it was able to find most of the other commands too.

Then I realized that this line should actually be pointed to the bin file.

For me that was "C:/Program Files/LaTeX/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/latex.exe".

It doesn't work perfect yet, but at least it is now able to read and compile something. I hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by restoring the default commands in TeXStudio. Follow a simmilar path to Teun

Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Commands > LaTeX

and click the arrow button to the right of each command.

Somehow the default commands were not restored even when I uninstalled and reinstalled TeXStudio. Not quite sure how that happened but this fix worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Close TeXStudio. In Windows Explorer navigate to some folder like: 
C:\Users\YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME\AppData\Roaming\texstudio

Delete texstudio.ini file.

Restart TeXStudio.

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Isn't possible to delete the trash fiels inside texstudio?With texmaker you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

put only in dvi something like that

DVI Viewer (view-dvi):  '"C:\Program Files (x86)\texmf\miktex\bin\yap.exe" -1 -s @?"c:ame "?am.dvi"'

and in another option put for default

Comment: You should NOT need to put c:\ifjfjfaf[iaf\ yap.exe blah blah That tells me other commands will fail **IT SHOULD  BE** yap.exe -1 -s @?"c:ame "?am.dvi"' and **if your path is configured correctly** it WILL WORK

Answer (score 0):

I installed miktex system wide manually
and then used `choco install texstudio` in powershell to install texstudio.

After that TeXstudio could find latex and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the portable version for both programs, I added the following two variables to my user environment (see below). Tthey can be added to the system environment as well, if one wants them to be available for everyone.

```
MIKTEX_HOME -> %APPS_MY%\miktex
MIKTEX_BIN -> %MIKTEX_HOME%\miktex\bin\x64
```

(`%APPS_MY%` should be replaced by the directory above `miktex`)

To add the variables, go to File Explorer -> Right click on This Computer -> Properties -> Advanced configuration -> User Environment

Answer (score 0):

I found this video setup is really helpful, especially if you have to use a portable version. Anyone who faces this problem can watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNvX-6V6v4s&ab_channel=ChandraHas

In short, you need to manually specify the binary executable files for **Latex, PdfLateX, XeLateX, LuaLaTeX, BibTeX, Biber, Makeindex, Makeglassaries** (which depend on your tex file needed to compile and generate PDF) as follows:

- Goto `Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Commands`
- Specify the above packages by locating to your downloaded MikTeX. For example:

  - LaTeX: `<path_to_portable_miktex>.../PortableSoft/miktex-portable/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/latex.exe`
  - PdfLaTeX: `<path_to_portable_miktex>.../PortableSoft/miktex-portable/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe`
  - and other packages.

After that, TexStudio might be required to install some additional packages during compiling, but they can be automatically detected, downloaded, and installed by TexStudio.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/214392)

Comment: @Werner: Thank you for your suggestion.