# Problem with installation of tabto

Tags: tabto

I am using mdpi class and getting the error "Unfortunately, the package tabto-ltx could not be installed." I am using Miktex+TexStudio. How to install tabto.ltx?

Comment: Have you tried the MikTeX console/package manager?

Comment: I installed it using MikTex console now error is "unable to install MikTex-Latex ", which is already installed

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing that error? Inside TeXstudio? Exactly what are you doing to generate it? Are the right commands/paths set in Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands? Can you compile from the command line? I can't find anything in TeXstudio's source code that would generate that error. I don't use MikTeX but [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367520/texstudio-does-not-find-miktex) might help.